# Jupyter missing version metadata

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to open jupyter and check an ipynb file but an error appears saying that there is no version attribute but I don't know how to fix it. If anyone knows how to, I'll be grateful.
The text on screen is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\D3ll\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main

File "C:\Users\D3ll\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 85, in 
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager

File "C:\Users\D3ll\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in 
from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError

File "C:\Users\D3ll\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 32, in 
from .validator import validate, ValidationError

File "C:\Users\D3ll\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in 
from jsonschema import ValidationError

File "C:\Users\D3ll\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 34, in 
__version__ = metadata.version("jsonschema")

AttributeError: module 'importlib_metadata' has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: I have the same problem after  updating anaconda navigator, any solution?

Comment: I just added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific version of json was 3.0.2 in the anaconda prompt I typed:

`pipenv install jsonschema==3.0.2`

taken from:
https://blog.gaborschulz.com/my-jupyter-notebook-stopped-working.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the module?

```
conda install importlib_metadata --force-reinstall
```

Comment: thank you, I had to install a specific json version to fix it.